# With iText7,How to specifies the width and color of strokes for text?

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, itext7

I's there any solution for iText 7 to specify the stroke width and stroke color for text?

The code I have tried so far:

```
using var doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("a4.pdf"));
var pageSize = PageSize.A4;
var page = doc.AddNewPage(pageSize);
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
var canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pageSize);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is a Paragraph");
p.SetFontSize(20f);
p.SetLineThrough();//can through line
//how to add a stroke to text?
canvas.ShowTextAligned(p, pageSize.GetLeft()+100, pageSize.GetTop() - 100, 1, iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.LEFT, iText.Layout.Properties.VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0f);
doc.Close();
using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        FileName = "a4.pdf"
    };
    process.Start();
}
```

I am looking for something that would look similar to the following HTML snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>     <meta charset="UTF-8" />     <style>       .demo {         color: white;         font-size: 40px;         -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgb(250, 190, 255);       }     </style>   </head>   <body>     <p class="demo">The Stroked Text</p>   </body> </html>
```

Comment: Just like -webkit-text-stroke in CSS.

Comment: @mkl need help..

Comment: Hi, can you attach the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Like css dose```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      .demo {
        color: white;
        font-size: 40px;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgb(250, 190, 255);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="demo">The Stroked Text</p>
  </body>
</html>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result similar to what you have in your HTML with the following styling settings:

```
p.SetStrokeColor(ColorConstants.PINK);
p.SetStrokeWidth(0.5f);
p.SetFontColor(ColorConstants.WHITE);
p.SetTextRenderingMode(PdfCanvasConstants.TextRenderingMode.FILL_STROKE);
```

Full code:

```
using var doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("a4.pdf"));
var pageSize = PageSize.A4;
var page = doc.AddNewPage(pageSize);
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
var canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pageSize);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is a Paragraph");
p.SetFontSize(20f);

p.SetStrokeColor(ColorConstants.PINK);
p.SetStrokeWidth(0.5f);
p.SetFontColor(ColorConstants.WHITE);
p.SetTextRenderingMode(PdfCanvasConstants.TextRenderingMode.FILL_STROKE);

canvas.ShowTextAligned(p, pageSize.GetLeft()+100, pageSize.GetTop() - 100, 1, iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.LEFT, iText.Layout.Properties.VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0f);
doc.Close();
using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        FileName = "a4.pdf"
    };
    process.Start();
}
```

Visual result:

[image: result]